# How to setup google analytics for a particular page and share that with particular users?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I already have GA implemented on my website, but now I want to track only specific page related activity using GA and give specific users access to view these activities.
I have not found any blog explaining this till now. Please help.

Comment: for each page in your website you need to send screen tag to GA. In dashboard you can view no.of views to particular screen based on tag

Comment: I do not want the other users to view any other page stats. They should be able to just see the stats for page I want them to. Is it possible.

Comment: As Eike Pierstorff points out, the best way to accomplish this is through the GA API.  And as he said, dealing with tokens and authentication, can be challenging.  I encourage you to check out http://www.embeddedanalytics.com (disclosure: I work with them).  We have done a number of dashboard implementations using filters based on page paths, domain, or other custom variables.  And we have developed methods to make these links "secure" (other users can't peek at the statistics of another user).  All done with minimal server side coding.

Comment: Yes we already have ga implemented on our server used for showing sight analytics and more. But this time we had to share the analytics with few managers for a short span of time, so I did not create a mail trigger myself instead used the GA's mail trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to set up a [custom report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en) (GA interface, top menu, "Customization") and have it mailed (via the "Email"-Button under the reports headline) to your users (you can choose custom intervals like daily, weekly etc). You can set a filter to include only specific pages (or only specific combinations of metrics and dimensions).

The other way is via the reporting API, the programming interface that allows you to pull data from Google Analytics. The problem here is not the report itself (the API is fairly easy to use) but access permissions. You cannot use the clientside login mechanism Google provides, because for that your users would need access to the Account in the first place. So you'd need some serverside mechanism that pulls the data and displays it based on the users permissions. This is a bit more involved, so for the moment I'll wait and see if custom reports work for you.

Also there are dashboard solutions that you can rent for a few bucks per month/user which I think include some sort of access management.

Comment: Suppose if I am tracking activities on www.example.com how would I add it to filter, I mean by selecting by which option, as it shows- Acquisition, Advertising, Behaviour etc.

Comment: If you want to filter by the domain name you can use a "hostname" filter.

Comment: Yup it saved a lot of time. Thanks again.